# iOS 7 iAds with TabBar Controller and Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, iad

I have a `UITabBarController` and `UINavigationController` in an app with storyboards that I want to use iAds in. I am using the BannerViewController.h & .m files provided by Apple in the iAdSuite demo. In tabbed views without a navigation controller, the `AdBannerView` loads fine. When I switch to the tab with a nav controller, there is a black bar (window) on the bottom of the screen above the tab bar. When the `AdBannerView` loads, it is moved over the black bar and the app looks fine. When it fails to load, the black bar is back. This black bar is also on every view pushed onto the nav controller stack when the `AdBannerView` isn't showing.

How can I remove this black bar?

This is the view when the AdBannerView hasn't loaded yet. Normally it has the blue background all the way down to the tab bar. The black bar has started to appear when using BannerViewController w/ tab bar & nav controllers
[image: AdBannerView did not load yet]
This is when the AdBannerView loads
[image: AdBannerView did load]

Here is some code:

In TabBarViewController.m:

```
//Implement BannerViewControllers on all the views in the Tab Bar
CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
UIStoryboard *storyboard = nil;
if (screenBounds.size.height == 568) {
    storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone4" bundle: nil];
} else {
    storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone35" bundle: nil];
}
UINavigationController *firstViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NavView"];
AboutViewController *secondViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AboutView"];
ContactViewController *thirdViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ContactView"];

NSMutableArray *mutArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[mutArray addObjectsFromArray:self.viewControllers];
[mutArray replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:[[BannerViewController alloc] initWithContentViewController:firstViewController]];
[mutArray replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:[[BannerViewController alloc] initWithContentViewController:secondViewController]];
[mutArray replaceObjectAtIndex:2 withObject:[[BannerViewController alloc] initWithContentViewController:thirdViewController]];
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithArray:mutArray];
[self setViewControllers:array];
```

Taken from TabbedBanner in iAdSuite:

In BannerViewController.m:

```
- (void)loadView
{
UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

// Setup containment of the _contentController.
[self addChildViewController:_contentController];
[contentView addSubview:_contentController.view];
[_contentController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

self.view = contentView;

}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
CGRect contentFrame = self.view.bounds, bannerFrame = CGRectZero;
ADBannerView *bannerView = [BannerViewManager sharedInstance].bannerView;
NSLog(@"Content frame before layout = %@",NSStringFromCGRect(contentFrame));

bannerFrame.size = [bannerView sizeThatFits:contentFrame.size];

if (bannerView.bannerLoaded) {
    contentFrame.size.height -= bannerFrame.size.height;
    bannerFrame.origin.y = contentFrame.size.height;
} else {
    bannerFrame.origin.y = contentFrame.size.height;
}
NSLog(@"Content frame after layout = %@",NSStringFromCGRect(contentFrame));

//_contentController.view.frame = contentFrame;
//I commented this out because AdBannerView will move the black bar up instead of covering it. 

// We only want to modify the banner view itself if this view controller is actually visible to the user.
// This prevents us from modifying it while it is being displayed elsewhere.
if (self.isViewLoaded && (self.view.window != nil)) {
    [self.view addSubview:bannerView];
    bannerView.frame = bannerFrame;

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Realizing the black bar is the window showing, I extended the contentController's frame by 50 to cover it up. I still don't know why it is only happening in a Tab+Nav Controller combo, but here is the code that fixed it

In BannerViewController.m:

```
- (void)loadView
{
UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

// Setup containment of the _contentController.
[self addChildViewController:_contentController];
[contentView addSubview:_contentController.view];
[_contentController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
_contentController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 618); //This is what saved me
self.view = contentView;

}
```